# onClick listener for every checkbox in a list

Tags: android, checkbox

I have created an arrayadapter with a list of checkboxes. Now, depending, on which checkbox is clicked, I would like to take in that particular checkbox's value. Can somebody please help?

Here is my code:

```
public void meth(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.product_name:
            if (checked)
            {
                final CheckBox cb01 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                A[i]=(String) cb01.getText();
                ++i;
                j=i;
                //savePreferences("checkb_1", true);
            }   
            break;
            default:break;
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, irrespective of how many checkboxes I'm selecting, only the value of the first checkbox is being taken and repeated by the number of checkboxes. That is, if I am choosing three checkboxes, all the three are being displayed in another activity, but with the same name as that of the first checkbox. Can somebody please help?

Comment: post the code how do you set on click listener to the checkbox?

Comment: The code posted above is a portion of the code from the java class. The code above shows my version of the on click listener. But I am not getting the desired output with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you've grabbed the checkbox for only one item in your list view.  You need to set an onClickListener on every item in your list.

There are two ways easy ways to do this:

1. list.setOnItemClickListener  This method puts the click listener on the whole row.
2. In arrayAdapter.getView, set view.setOnClickListener, or set it on the actual checkbox:

   ```
   public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

   // Create a cell, or clear an existing one.
   if (view == null) {
       view = activityContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_cell, parent, false);
   }
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
   cb.setOnClickListener(YOUR ON CLICK LISTENER)
   }
   ```

I've left out some of the normal error checking code in getView.

Comment: Hi GLee, thank u for your reply. If I were to write OnClickListener for the list, can you please tell me how to call every checkbox in it?

Comment: You reference the checkbox by position, so for instance, in getView, you have access to `int position`.  Use that to pull out the data that you need from the list in your arrayadapter.

Comment: Well, I am now using textviews inside the arraylist, instead of checkboxes. I am able to perform onClickListener and retrieve the values of textviews. I am also setting a feature of changing the background color when an item is selected. I would like do the same when the item is clicked again, that is de-selected. Can you please help me?